# pandas get data frame from uneven nested list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a nested list

```
nl = [[['04-05-2021', '05-05-2021', '06-05-2021'],[2240, 3528, 2800]],[['03-05-2021', '04-05-2021', '05-05-2021'],[123032, 18312, 123872]]]
```

I want to convert it into a data frame that looks like this:

```
**Desired output is as follows:**

DATE            1      2
03-05-2021      0     123032
04-05-2021      2240  18312
05-05-2021      3528  123872
06-05-2021      2800  0
```

The nested list always has two lists one with the date and another with the value.  I am trying to create a data frame matching the date and fill nan with zero.  I tried the following:

```
    kk=[]
    for bd in bydatedata:
            kk.append(pd.DataFrame(bd).T)

    kk1=pd.concat(kk,axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    print(kk1)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
0             1      2           3
04-05-2021    2240   03-05-2021  123032
05-05-2021    3528   04-05-2021  18312
06-05-2021    2800   05-05-2021  123872
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lsit comprehension with `Series` and pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last replace missing values:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(b, index=a) for a, b in nl], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
               0       1
04-05-2021  2240   18312
05-05-2021  3528  123872
06-05-2021  2800       0
03-05-2021     0  123032
```